# query on nuget packages loading at runtime in .net standard projects

Tags: .net, azure, nuget, .net-standard

I created a sample class library in VS2017 which has a method to register a device in azure IOT hub . I set the target framework as .Net Standard 1.6 so that this can be used  by clients that comply to this standard. Also want to try out .net standard :)

I added reference to the latest version of Microsoft.Azure.Devices (1.4.1) required for communicating with azure IOT hub via nuget. completed the device registration part. no compile errors. To test it out I referred this assembly in a console app and called the function.
Got a runtime error that

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Then I noticed that this dll was not found in the bin folder of the console app and the assembly project as well. Normally the nuget dependencies get downloaded and copied to bin. 
Also there is no nuget packages folder in this case.
I checked out this blog post https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx and tried the packagereference option as well.
nothing happened.
I am not sure what am I missing here . could be a basic error that one should follow while using .net standard target.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I created my .Net Standard 1.6 class library and referenced [Microsoft.Azure.Devices 1.4.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices/1.4.1). For .Net Standard 1.6, I created my .NET Framework console application that targets 4.6.1 and referenced the .Net Standard 1.6 class library. I could encounter the same issue as you mentioned, after follow the tutorial you provided, I edited the `*.csproj` of my console application and rebuilt it, then it could work as expected on my side.

Without specifying the `PackageReference` for my .NET Framework console application, I could not find the `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.dll` under my bin folder. In summary, you need to check whether the related dlls have been copied to the bin folder of your console app.

Comment: interesting. I did try the same steps I had explained and the dlls were not copied to the bin folder of that project.  Ideally one should not be editing the csproj manually.